# Symfony2 + AJAX: Can't fetch data in controller

Tags: ajax, symfony, doctrine-orm

## Problem

I'm using Symfony2 with AJAX to insert a new record in my 'locations' table.
I can easily pass the data I want from the form to my Controller that handles that
AJAX request. I checked with Firebug and all the GET values are as I wanted.
Just to be clear the controller is not in the location controller but in the debug controller, don't know if that matters. (just for sandbox-testing atm).

Because of the relationships in the database the location entity has a district column which needs a district-entity object.

Problem is now this code is returning the succes response fine if I leave out the $em->flush(). If I add the $em->flush() to perform the insert, I get an 500 Internal error in my console of my browser.

Here's the code for my controller:

```
        $request = $this->container->get('request');
        if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){

              $street = $request->query->get('street');
              $zip = $request->query->get('zip');
              $lat = $request->query->get('lat');
              $name = $request->query->get('name');
              $number = $request->query->get('number');

              // insert into object
              $entity  = new Location();
              $entity->setStreet($street);
              $entity->setZip($zip);
              $entity->setLat($lat);
              $entity->setName($name);
              $entity->setNumber($number);


              $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
              $district = new District();
              // get the district hard coded for testing
              $district = $em->getRepository("SnowFrontBundle:District")->find(7);
              $entity->setDistrict($district);
              //$entity->setDistrict(null);
              $em->persist($entity);
              $em->flush();
              //prepare the response, e.g.
              $response = array("code" => 100, "success" => true);
              return new Response(json_encode($response));
        }
```

## Question

What could be wrong with the $em->flush() part? How can I see what the real error is? (instead of 500 internal error). As well should I be using a createFormBuilder?

Comment: 1. Why won't you use Symfony built-in form framework? 2. If you're receiving 500 Internal Error you're probably working in production environment instead of development.

Comment: And what does it give you if you dont access this with Ajax but just a normal post? @Crozin Ajax does return a 500 Internal Error is something goes wrong even in development environment.

Comment: Crozin is right, you can see the stack trace if you work in the development environment, even in the console.

Comment: When the user ads a location, I want the latitude and longitude in the database aswell. That's why I use Ajax first of all, because I get the lat and long from the Google Maps API first and than send that with the other data to the controller. Second of all is the 'add location' some sort of popup in another form, so no new page -> ajax.

The console just gives me the 500 internal server error. I get this in the 'net' part in Firebug:
http://gyazo.com/ad206cab0e9bfa96c89c90aa9051349f

I can't really make something out of it...

Comment: Maybe you are inserting wrong values into your DB? Since you don't validate your data it only gives you the error once you try to insert it into your DB.

Comment: I added a comment so I could paste my new code in it. @Schwierig how can i validate the data?

Comment: Never mind, it's fixed! :D finally, apparently the problem was I had a column named 'long' for the longitude, but that gave a problem with the 'long' keyword :/ so just had to change the name in the database. Thanks anyway guys!